# How to list blog posts filtered by a tag on Odoo (v14)

Tags: odoo, tags, blogs, odoo-14

I use Odoo Blog module for adding news on our website with using tags. I would like to add block of last few posts in different pages, filtered by specific tag. Unfortunately, by default, there is no such snippet option.

[image: Odoo Blog Posts snippet options]

I checked the code that is generated with this snippet (see below).

```
<section class="s_latest_posts pt16 pb16 o_colored_level" data-vcss="001" data-snippet="s_latest_posts" data-name="Blog Posts">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row s_col_no_bgcolor s_nb_column_fixed js_get_posts s_latest_posts_card s_latest_posts_effect_marley" data-loading="true" data-template="website_blog.s_latest_posts_card_template" data-filter-by-blog-id="0" data-order="published_date desc"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

There is a filter by blog id  `data-filter-by-blog-id="0"` I'm trying to do something similar but with `tag_ids`. Do you have any idea how to do?